# Automatic user log-in on a PHP-Website by button-clicking on a 3rd party .NET application

Tags: c#, php, .net

Our customer is developing a C#.NET desktop software whilst we are hosting a website.

Our (PHP) website (no framework in use) has an user area for logged-in users.

The plan (yes, we are collecting ideas right now) is to let the user who is clicking on the button gets automatically logged in on our website and see their own user area on the web browser.

Our idea is to use OAuth 2.0, but I suppose that's not the right way since that one is commonly used for fetching resources from a protected resource server. And we got no clue which of the 4 flows we got to stick to, not even knowing what would be the client (role) in this scenery.

They might send some kind of code (json, curl, whatever...) with the LDAP information (Email? Username? First-/Lastname?) so we check in our database if the user is registered maybe? Would you recommend that we are writing our own solution by trying this, letting them in as if they used the login form on our site? Or is there any best-practice, technology, framework or anything we could take a look at first?

Comment: User clicks button in desktop app and is logged in in browser hosted in that same app? Or in external browser? How you identify that user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a sso (single sign on) authentication,

Different SSO protocols share session information in different ways, but the essential concept is the same:

> there is a central domain, through which authentication is performed

and then the session is shared with other domains in some way. For instance, the central domain may generate a signed JSON Web Token (which may be encrypted using JWE).

[image]

ref:
https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/